# how to access to my web application with private ip address

Tags: web-applications, glassfish

i have the following issue:

i have a glassfish web application located on a virtual host with a corresponding private ip address in my LAN .I also have a domain name associated to my public ip address. Now i want to  make my web application available ouside the LAN, in other word i want to access my web application, located on my private ip address, by typing my domain name, for example `http://cts.mydomain.it` (which have the public ip address). How can i do that???

I hope someone help me

Answer (score -2):

get the public ip address equivalent of your private ip address.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.